# lineChart not updating even if using the same dimension

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, linechart, dc.js

I have a `lineChart` with a somewhat complicated `.valueAccessor` function. I also have a `barChart` on the same dimension and group.

There are several other charts on the webpage but on other dimensions and groups.

When I filter using one of the other charts, the `barChart` updates correctly but not the `lineChart`. Could there be something explaining that behaviour ?

I would like to get feedback before setting up a jsFiddle as my data is quite heavy.

EDIT : here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZFx4/1/). It pulls 7MB of data in an ajax call so it takes a while to run. The answer provided by @DJMartin below should be the fix for me but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post how the `.valueAccessor` is been calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the crossfilter API reference: https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference

"Note: a grouping intersects the crossfilter's current filters, except for the associated dimension's filter. Thus, group methods consider only records that satisfy every filter except this dimension's filter. So, if the crossfilter of payments is filtered by type and total, then groupAll by total only observes the filter by type."

If you create a second dimension using the same property, the filtering will reflect across charts.

Here is an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/nw8EV/.

```
teamMemberChart
        .width(270)
        .height(220)
        .dimension(teamMemberDimension)
        .group(teamMemberGroup)
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.projectCount;
    })
        .elasticX(true);

    teamMemberChart2
        .width(270)
        .height(220)
        .dimension(teamMemberDimension)
        .group(teamMemberGroup)
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.projectCount;
    })
        .elasticX(true);

    teamMemberChart3
        .width(270)
        .height(220)
        .dimension(teamMemberDimension2)
        .group(teamMemberGroup2)
        .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.projectCount;
    })
        .elasticX(true);
```

The first two charts use the same dimension - picking one option does not reflect the other.  The third chart uses a different dimension on the same property - choosing an option on this chart updates the other two charts.

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle. That is exactly what I need. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected in my webpage. I have recreated for you the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZFx4/1/). It takes a little while to run as the Ajax call pulls 7MB of data. I would be very grateful if you could have a look.

Comment: Please try to isolate the problem by simplifying your use case.  Do you have the same issue without your custom reduce and without your custom valueAccessor?  Can you reproduce the problem with a simpler data set than the 7MB of data?  In my experience, isolating the problem often leads to finding the solution yourself but if not I'd be happy to help if you could do a little more of the initial legwork.

Comment: It does work with a basic accessor function so I'll look in that direction and possibly ask a separate question here. Thanks for your help.